# Django : modelformset not reflecting initial data

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

i am trying to create a form to edit skills of user where they have saved multiple no. of skills. after rendering the template input fields are empty but the no. of form created is correct as per queryset.

## forms.py

```
class skillform(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Skill',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',}))
    level = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(('Novice','Novice'),('Beginner','Beginner'),('Skillful','Skillful'),('Experienced','Experienced'),('Expert','Expert')),label="level",initial='Skillful',widget=forms.Select(),required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = userskills_model
        fields = ('name','level')
skillformset =  modelformset_factory(userskills_model, form = skillform, extra=0, can_delete=False)
```

## models.py

```
class userskills_model(models.Model):
    userid = models.ForeignKey(user_model, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    skills =models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=False,blank=False,null=False)
    skills_level = models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=False,blank=False,null=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.userid)
```

## views.py

```
def skillview(request):
    qset=userskills_model.objects.filter( userid=user_model.objects.get(userid=userid))
    skillformset(queryset = qset)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        formset = skillformset(request.GET or None)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        formset = skillformset(request.POST)
        #validating and saving
    return render(request, template_name, {
    'formset': formset,
})
```

## template/skills.html

```
{% extends 'app/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles%}
{% block head %}
<link href="{% static "/css/skills.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" 
type="text/css"/>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="heading_text">SKILLS</div>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset %}
<div class="row form-row spacer">
    <div class="col-5">
        <label>{{form.name.label}}</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            {{form.name}}
            </div>


    </div>
    <div class="col-5">
        <label>{{form.level.label}}</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            {{form.level}}
            <!-- <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-success add-form-row">+</button>
            </div> -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-success add-form-row">+</button>
    </div>
</div>

{% endfor %}
<div class="row spacer">
    <div class="col-3 button1">
        <button type="submit" class="btn3">Save and Continue</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>


{% endblock %}
{% block custom_js %}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     function updateElementIndex(el, prefix, ndx) {
var id_regex = new RegExp('(' + prefix + '-\\d+)');
var replacement = prefix + '-' + ndx;
if ($(el).attr("for")) $(el).attr("for", 
$(el).attr("for").replace(id_regex, replacement));
if (el.id) el.id = el.id.replace(id_regex, replacement);
if (el.name) el.name = el.name.replace(id_regex, replacement);}
function cloneMore(selector, prefix) {
var newElement = $(selector).clone(true);
var total = $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
newElement.find(':input').each(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('name')
    if(name) {
        name = name.replace('-' + (total-1) + '-', '-' + total + '-');
        var id = 'id_' + name;
        $(this).attr({'name': name, 'id': id}).val('').removeAttr('checked');}});
total++;
$('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(total);
$(selector).after(newElement);
var conditionRow = $('.form-row:not(:last)');
conditionRow.find('.btn.add-form-row')
.removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
.removeClass('add-form-row').addClass('remove-form-row')
.html('-');
return false;}
function deleteForm(prefix, btn) {
var total = parseInt($('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val());
if (total > 1){
    btn.closest('.form-row').remove();
    var forms = $('.form-row');
    $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(forms.length);
    for (var i=0, formCount=forms.length; i<formCount; i++) {
        $(forms.get(i)).find(':input').each(function() {
            updateElementIndex(this, prefix, i);
        });
    }
}
return false;}
$(document).on('click', '.add-form-row', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
cloneMore('.form-row:last', 'form');
return false;});
 $(document).on('click', '.remove-form-row', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
deleteForm('form', $(this));
return false;});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

edit:added the template/skills.html . i m stuck with this please help me out here

Comment: try: `if request.method == 'GET':
        formset = skillformset()`

Comment: thanks for replying......but thats not working and still input fields are empty @Matt

Comment: can you show us your template?

Comment: i have edited with adding template .please check it and help @Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields you have declared on your `skillform` do not exist on `userskills_model` so they won't be populated with anything. Try renaming the fields on your form to `skills` and `skills_model` so they match your model:

```
class skillform(forms.ModelForm):
    skills = forms.CharField(label='Skill',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',}))
    skills_level = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(('Novice','Novice'),('Beginner','Beginner'),('Skillful','Skillful'),('Experienced','Experienced'),('Expert','Expert')),label="level",initial='Skillful',widget=forms.Select(),required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = userskills_model
        fields = ('skills','skills_level')
```

and update your template to reference `form.skills` and `form.skills_level`:

```
...
{% for form in formset %}
<div class="row form-row spacer">
    <div class="col-5">
        <label>{{form.skills.label}}</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            {{form.skills}}
            </div>


    </div>
    <div class="col-5">
        <label>{{form.skills_level.label}}</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            {{form.skills_level}}
            ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess your qset is empty, try this - 
qset=userskills_model.objects.filter( userid=self.request.user) # This for logged in user

For update case - 
user = get_object_or_404(user_model, userid=userid)
qset=userskills_model.objects.filter( userid=user)